# How to run PHP script with post form tag in terminal?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, linux

I am trying to create my own method of receiving texts which are alerts from a website. In this script I am using php, I get the html of a site on another domain, then paste its html into the current page, then use jquery to extract information from it, then use its click() button to submit a form with the data in a textarea tag, which then gets passed to a php code. There I send a text with the info to me. This works so far. But now I am trying to automate this in putty terminal using cron. But using the command `nohup php myscript.php`, it seems to run the php file, but I am not recieving any texts. I think it has something to do with the submit button.

Does anyone know a technique that I can use to solve this problem so that the putty code above will work?

Thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Test
        </title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="Includes/jquery-1.8.1.min.js">
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <?php

            $Fname = $_POST["new_movies"];
            if (isset($Fname)) {
                $formatted_number = "4163958750@msg.telus.com";
                $pieces = explode("\n", $Fname);

                $count = 0;
                $build = "";

                foreach ($pieces as &$value) {
                    $build = $build.$value."\n";

                    $count = $count + 1;
                    if ($count==2) {
                        $count = 0;
                        mail("$formatted_number", "", "$build");
                        $build = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $contents = file_get_contents( "http://extratorrent.com/" );
                echo "$contents";
            }
        ?>

        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" style="display:none">
            <textarea rows="5" cols="20" id="my_text_field" name="new_movies" wrap="physical"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input id="my_submit_button" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></input>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                var build = "";

                var g = $('.tl').eq(0);
                g = $('.tlr, .tlz', $(g));

                for (var i=0; i<g.length; i+=1) {
                    val = $ ( 'a', $ ('td', g[i]) ).attr('title');
                    val = val.substr(9);
                    val = val.substring(0, val.length-8);
                    build += val;

                    if (i < g.length-1) {
                        build += '\n';
                    }
                }
                $('#my_text_field').val(build);
                if ($('#my_text_field').val().trim() != "") { 
                    $('#my_submit_button').click();
                }
        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A question like "can someone rewrite this code" is usually not well received here. My recommendation is that you to try something and come back here if that doesn't work.

Comment: ok i edited my question above.

Comment: Are you sure that when you call `myscript.php` you're in the right directory? I highly doubt that you are.

Comment: yes I am, because it writes the code of the file in the termainal